# Разбить массив Mysql на строки php

Tags: php, строки

Я только изучаю php и mysql, хотел узнать, возможно ли разбить массив такого вида:

```
lorem
ipsum 
dolor 
sit 
amet
```

Разбить отдельные строки и вывести циклом каждую строку отдельно,
пробовал explode но он только пробелы учитывал, а необходимо делать выборку с учетом переноса строки.

Comment: То что вы показываете - это не массив.

Comment: Мда. Вам нужно строку разбить на массив. В `explode` можно задать разный разделитель. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php поможет при более сложном разделителе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено -

```
$lines = explode("\n", $data->list);
$count_lines = count($lines);

foreach (range(0, $count_lines) as $number) 
    echo '<li><a href="#"">'.$lines[$number].'</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Осталось ещё почитать про цикл foreach. ;)